# How to lock cells

Tags: macos, excel, locking, cells

say i have 7 groups of 2 columns (14 columns in total) & many rows like "ab" "cd" "ef" ect... but i want to lock one the cells in that column say "a1" has a value  then "b1" should be lock or if "b1" has a value then "a1" should be lock automatic like the otherones "cd" "ef" ... But not to change any other cells only the ones in their group ab cd ef ect..

more exp:: if c20 have a value or number then d20 should be lock

my sheet is base on profit or lose so i dont want 1 profit or 1 lose to be entered in the same group "ab" "cd" "ef"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent data entry with Data Validation (offered as an alternative to locking cells) and a Custom formula such as `=B1=""` in A1 and `=A1=""` in B1. For each such pair only the first entered value will be accepted.

Comment: thank you.     now is theres a way to not have to enter it for every single cells because i have alot of cells

Comment: i got it =b1:b158"" so i got it thank you very much

Comment: now i need help making a whole columns has a negative value